# Triggered event only once every time it is scrolled to

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have some event, when user scroll to element «itemSection1». But this event will be repeated many times, as the user will scroll on until this element is finished. How can I make the event triggered only once every time it is scrolled to?

When i reach this element next time i need this event one more time

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.itemSection1').offset().top - 150) {
   
    $('.scrollLinks a').removeClass('active');
    $('.menuItem1').addClass('active');

    alert('Hello!'); // some event that i need only once on reaching

    } else {
    
    $('. menuItem1').removeClass('active');
    
    }
    });
```

Comment: I mean show alert only time every time when i scroll to menuItem1

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76542105/2314737

Answer (score 0):

You want to trigger some action after scrolling but only once a certain offset is reached. Since after passing a certain treshold you add the class `"active"`, you could use that information.

Check if the element already has the class `"active"`

```
 // add class etc only if not already added
        if (!($("p").hasClass("active"))) {
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 5) {
           // add class etc only if not already added
            if (!($("p").hasClass("active"))) {
                $("p").addClass("active");
                $('.scrollLinks a').removeClass('active');
                $('.menuItem1').addClass('active');
                alert('Hello!'); // some event that i need only once on reaching
              }
            }
            else {

              $('p').removeClass('active');

            }
          })
      });
```

```css
p {
  background: green;
  height: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll down this page.</p>
```